# Problems after downloading Ubuntu

Tags: flash

I've just downloaded Ubuntu now I have an Adobe message saying "it isn't a supported file type or the file has been damaged" . I've tried again and got the same result.

Comment: Saying the Ubuntu iso is unsupported?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: adobe can't open isos.

Comment: you want PowerISO.  google it to find the version for your computer.